# Incorrect capitalization in UILabel

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, uifont

The code I am using:

```
@IBOutlet weak var tlabel: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tlabel.font = UIFont(name: "Anxiety", size: 40)
    tlabel.numberOfLines = 0
    tlabel.text = "Test"
}
```

The text "Test" gets capitalized ("TEST" appears on the screen). How can I avoid this?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Does TEXT or TEST appear on the screen?

Answer (score 2):

A quick google seems to show that the font Anxiety does not have any non capital letters in the font. So if you want to use non capital letters you have to find another font.

http://www.1001freefonts.com/anxiety.font